# how to re-use code when you need separate event handlers

Tags: c#

I have two methods that are almost identical.  The only difference is that I have two separate events for the click event on the button click.  Is there a clean way to transform this into one method call?  Can I pass in an event name in the method parameter list?  If I instantiate two different events and pass them into the same method, I need each event to have it's own event handling method definition (crowdDynoButtonClick_Event and playerDynoButtonClick_Event)

```
 private void loadChildCrowdObjectsOnScreen(UniformGrid ug) {
            foreach (PlayerCrowdObjectBO childObject in childCrowdObjectOC) {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Tag = childObject.ObjectNbr;
                b.Height = 25;
                b.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                b.Content = childObject.ObjectName + "  #" + childObject.ObjectNbr;
                b.Click += crowdDynoButtonClick_Event;
                ug.Children.Add(b);
            }
        }

 private void loadChildPlayerObjectsOnScreen(UniformGrid ug) {
            foreach (PlayerCrowdObjectBO childObject in childPlayerObjectOC) {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Tag = childObject.ObjectNbr;
                b.Height = 25;
                b.Margin = new Thickness(5);
                b.Content = childObject.ObjectName + "  #" + childObject.ObjectNbr;
                b.Click += playerDynoButtonClick_Event;
                ug.Children.Add(b);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perhaps pass a delegate as a parameter?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could go for an extraction of the event handler

```
private void loadCrowdObjectsOnScreen(UniformGrid ug, RoutedEventHandler handler) {
    foreach (PlayerCrowdObjectBO childObject in childCrowdObjectOC) {
       Button b = new Button();
       b.Tag = childObject.ObjectNbr;
       b.Height = 25;
       b.Margin = new Thickness(5);
       b.Content = childObject.ObjectName + "  #" + childObject.ObjectNbr;
       b.Click += handler;
       ug.Children.Add(b);
    }
 }
```

Note: I'm not sure what your `handler` type is, you may have to enhance this to apply to your code.

Comment: Assuming it's Windows Forms, Button inherits Click from Control which is EventHandler. So, no problem. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.click(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: How do I send the EventHandler into the method and tell it "Go to this specific method when the event is triggered"?

Comment: How did you do when you used to call your method `loadChildPlayerObjectsOnScreen` ? Do the exact same thing now, calling `loadCrowdObjectsOnScreen` but you pass `playerDynoButtonClick_Event` as a parameter

Comment: @ArthurAttout - but I am creating the 'elapsed' event on the fly.  I don't create that when I instantiate the timer.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. How did you do until now ? When you used to call `loadChildCrowdObjectsOnScreen`, what was `crowdDynoButtonClick_Event` for example ? I suppose you had a global variable and you called your method. Why can't you do the same thing now but passing your global variable as a parameter ?

Comment: The line 'b.Click += crowdDynoButtonClick_Event;' is where the event handler is declared.  Then I have a private void method to handle the click event.  I am not instantiating the event anywhere.

Comment: How do you declare the event? `b.Click += /*what is here?*/;`, is it `crowdDynoButtonClick_Event`? what is the name of the "private void method"? is it `crowdDynoButtonClick_Event`?

Comment: Yes, that is how I declare the event:  'b.Click += crowdDynoButtonClick_Event;  The name of the private void method is: crowdDynoButtonClick_Event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){}

Comment: How do you call `loadChildCrowdObjectsOnScreen` method now?

Comment: UniformGrid ug = this.ug_crowdContainer;
 loadChildCrowdObjectsOnScreen(ug);

Comment: Now if you use this solution you have to do this `UniformGrid ug = this.ug_crowdContainer; loadCrowdObjectsOnScreen(ug, crowdDynoButtonClick_Event);loadCrowdObjectsOnScreen(ug, playerDynoButtonClick_Event);`

Comment: ok, how do you instantiate crowdDynoButtonClick_Event or playerDynoButtonClick_Event before you send them into the method call?

Comment: It is already instantiated as you have `private void crowdDynoButtonClick_Event` method declared. You can pass a method by it's name to another method.

Comment: @ArthurAttout Looks like OP is using WPF, hence the `Click` event has [this signature](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.buttonbase.click(v=vs.110).aspx). Change `EventHandler handler` to `RoutedEventHandler handler` and hopefully the issue will be solved.

Comment: @IvanStoev - I tried this.  It blows up with an object exception.

Comment: What is that Exception? Can you post the exception message?

Comment: I worked with it this morning and found my issue.  It works.  I learned a lot.  Thank you so much for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with just keeping it simple with two event handlers and one method?

```
private void loadChildCrowdObjectsOnScreen(UniformGrid ug) {
    DoStuff(childCrowdObjectOC);
}

private void loadChildPlayerObjectsOnScreen(UniformGrid ug) {
    DoStuff(childPlayerObjectOC);
}

private void DoStuff(List<PlayerCrowdObjectBO> objs){

    foreach (PlayerCrowdObjectBO childObject in objs) {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Tag = childObject.ObjectNbr;
        b.Height = 25;
        b.Margin = new Thickness(5);
        b.Content = childObject.ObjectName + "  #" + childObject.ObjectNbr;
        b.Click += playerDynoButtonClick_Event;
        ug.Children.Add(b);
    }

}
```

Comment: I would appreciate the idea, but there are 2 problems here need to be fixed. 1. `DoStuff` has no definition for `ug` used in the last line, 2. you forgot `crowdDynoButtonClick_Event`

Comment: the "_Event" handlers need to do two different things, which is why I needed to pass in the handlers...